# How to have a TCP connection await until previous connection is closed before starting a new one

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, async-await, tcp

I am using Python, sockets, selectors

I have a list such as [1,2,3,4,5]

I want to open up a connection, send an item from the list, close down the connection and repeat for the next item on the list.

The method to open up a connection:

```
def start_connections(connid, current_message):

    server_addr = (host, port)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setblocking(False)
    sock.connect_ex(server_addr)

    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE

    data = types.SimpleNamespace(
        connid=connid,
        recv_total=0,
        messages=current_message,
        outb=b"",
    )
    sel.register(sock, events, data=data)
```

And this is the method used to determine the amount of connections to start up:

```
def number_of_connections(num_conns):
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1

        current_message = messages[i]
        start_connections(connid, current_message)

        events = sel.select(timeout=1)
        if events:
            for key, mask in events:
                service_connection(key, mask)
```

I believe this is the method where I would need to implement some type of async/await functionality but I'm not sure if it's a correct approach

And for reference this is the method which read and writes to the server, the intention is a connection is closed down when the server writes back to the client

```
def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data

    while True:
        if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
            recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
            if recv_data:
               
                data.recv_total += len(recv_data)

            if not recv_data or data.recv_total == 24:
                sel.unregister(sock)
                sock.close()
                break

        if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
            if not data.outb and data.messages:
                data.outb = data.messages

            if data.outb:
                
                sent = sock.send(data.outb)
                data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
```

To summarize, I want to open up an x amount of connections and each one is closed down when the server writes back to the client on that connection. The main problem I have been having is the program will start up all connections at once, do some work and then close all connections. After trying to fix that, the problem I am currently having is having the `number_of_connection` method to await until a `service_connection` method is finished.

Comment: You need to make it so that when your program closes one connection, it opens another one.

Comment: By the way your `service_connection` function doesn't work. It just loops forever, and keeps trying to read/write even if there's nothing left to read/write because the mask isn't updated

Comment: How do I make it so a new connection is opened after one closes? Coming from javascript you can do async/await but I'm just not sure if that's a correct approach or if you can do it in python

Comment: Python just runs the commands in order. You know the part where you close the connection? Yeah, on the next line, put the commands to open a new one.... Then the computer will open a new one after it closes the old one....

Comment: but your overall program has problems and I'm not sure you really know how to use these selectors and keys. So don't! Is there a reason why you need to use selectors and keys and setblocking(False)?